# Guardar nuevo archivo o Reemplazar archivo existente SQL C#.net

Tags: c#, sql

Estoy con un proyecto que almacena documentos, Mi duda es como puedo almacenarlos y que SQL me diga si existe el documento con el mismo nombre o ID.

Este es el código SQL:

```sql
USE [HConDe]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[ActualizarDocumento]    Script Date: 11/09/2018 10:54:51 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[ActualizarDocumento]

@iddocu int, @nomdocu varchar(50), @fechadocu date, @contdocu varchar(max)


as 

--ActualizarDocumento

if not exists (SELECT id_documento from Documento where id_documento=@iddocu)

insert into Documento (id_documento,nombre_documento,fecha_documento,contenido_documento) values (@iddocu, @nomdocu , @fechadocu, @contdocu)

else print 'Archivo existe'
```

En C# lo ejecuto. El problema es que me reemplaza el archivo sin ningún dialogo antes. Quería saber como podría hacerlo..

```
public override bool Guardar()          
{
    try {

        string cmd = String.Format("EXEC ActualizarDocumento '{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}'", txtiddocu.Text.Trim(), txtDocu.Text.Trim(), dt1.Value.ToString(), rich.Trim());
        utlidades.Ejecutar(cmd);
        MessageBox.Show("Se ha guardado correctamente");
        return true;

    }
    catch(Exception error) {

        MessageBox.Show("Se ha producido un error: " + error.Message);
        return false;

    }
}
```

Comment: No te sirve realizar esa validación en C#?

Comment: Como lo pensarias? @PauloUrbanoRivera

Comment: Es muy recomendable que siempre el código esté en formato de texto, no en imagen. Mas info en [ask]

Comment: @IbarraEmiliano realizar un `select` con condición `where` en tu código y si te trae información (distinto de nulo) es porque el registro ya existe y envías un mensaje al usuario

Comment: No creo que el código que nos enviaste sea el que estas utilizando.... estas diciendo que el documento es reemplazado, pero aqui no hay ningun update, solo insert

Answer (score 0):

Tu SP no esta haciendo ningún `UPDATE` cuando existe el archivo esta es la solución:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT id_documento FROM Documento WHERE id_documento=@iddocu)
    INSERT INTO Documento (id_documento,nombre_documento,fecha_documento,contenido_documento) 
    VALUES (@iddocu, @nomdocu , @fechadocu, @contdocu)
ELSE
    UPDATE Documento SET 
        nombre_documento = @nomdocu, 
        fecha_documento = @fechadocu, 
        contenido_documento = @contdocu 
    WHERE id_documento=@iddocu
```